# How do we get Alexa to speak instead of making the light green when receiving a message?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I sent a message via my Alexa app to my friends Alexa app. But when he received the message his echo device gives a small sound and turns it's round light to green.

Instead of this can we get Alexa to prompt and say that "you got a message do you want me to read it"?

Is there any skill that I need to install for this?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, not possible. I found this:

> Once received, the recipient’s Echo will light up and make a chime noise, but Alexa won’t announce that there’s a message (unlike how she does when there’s a call). However, they’ll also receive a notification on their phone and can view or listen to the message within the Alexa app.

https://www.google.fi/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/306818/how-to-call-and-message-friends-using-your-amazon-echo/amp/